# Custom Key Generation in Spring Caching

Tags: java, spring, caching

I just have started working on Spring caching.

This is the class in which I have implemented caching:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames="empcache")
public class General {  

    @Cacheable
    public String getDetails(int empId) {

        if(empId==1) {
            System.out.println("Inside getDetails. Emp id is 1.");
            return "Amar";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Emp id is not 1.");
            return "Anthony";
        }
    }
}
```

This is a custom bean which I will user for Key Generation:

```
@Component
public class Temp {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }   
}
```

My context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.packages.beans" />
<cache:annotation-driven key-generator="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator"/>

<bean id ="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator" class="com.packages.beans.myKeyGenerator"/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" 
                        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
                        p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
```

Below is the custom key Generation class:

```
public class MyKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    @Autowired 
    private Temp temp1;

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object arg0, Method arg1, Object... arg2) { 

        String key =  temp1.getName() + temp1.getSurname() + "_" + arg1.getName();
        System.out.println("key is "+key);

        return key;
    }   
}
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Temp generate=new Temp();
    generate.setName("ABC");
    generate.setSurname("DEF");

    ApplicationContext context =  new   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    General main=(General) context.getBean("mybean");   

    System.out.println(main.getDetails(main.getEmpId()));
}
```

When I am running the program from the main method setting the the value of temp in it. I am getting the key in keyGenerator class as null_null_getDetails and not as ABC_DEF_getDetails.

But I need the key to be composed of the values that I prefill in the custom bean temp.

Comment: The problem is related to Spring Managed beans, vs. creating your own class instances using 'new'.  When you execute generate=new temp(); then spring is not managing this instance.  So it is not @autowired as you expect it to be.

Comment: thanks for the input it worked

Answer (score 0):

The 'Temp' you are creating in main is not part of the spring context.
Instead spring creates a bean 'temp' from

```
@Component
public class Temp
```

But there name and surename are null. This instance of Temp is used for your keyGenerator and that's why you get the nulls in the key.

You must create a bean of Temp with the already set name and surname.
In java config you can do that like :

```
@Bean
Temp temp() {
   Temp generate=new Temp();
   generate.setName("ABC");
   generate.setSurname("DEF");
   return temp; 
}
```